# How to create a modal window

Tags: cocoa, window, modal-dialog

I am very new in cocoa for MAC. I created a NSWindow and i add a NSButton as subview in the NSWindow.

I want to show a modal window from click the NSButton. I saw the http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/WinPanel/Concepts/UsingModalWindows.html reference. But it is not so easy for beginner like me.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Modal dialogs are not as prevalent in the Mac operating system and are generally considered bad form.  The only truly accepted modal dialog is a sheet which you attach to the window that it applies to.

Avoid modal modes when programming for the Mac when possible.

**References**:

- http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Sheets/Sheets.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000002-BABFIBIA
- http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?DisplayingSheets

Comment: thanx for the sharing documentation